# How to build a retrieved data from a form page to another page using list view builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi there I’m new to flutter and this app takes an input from a user and outputs a list with the value from the text field all in one page but what I wanted was it to output the list view builder in another page with the value from the text field in another page I’ll be greatful if anyone can help,this is the code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => new _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  List<String> _items = new List(); // to store comments

  final myController = TextEditingController();

  void _addComment() {
    if (myController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      // check if the comments text input is not empty
      setState(() {
        _items.add(myController.text); // add new commnet to the existing list
      });

      myController.clear(); // clear the text from the input
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("DEMO")),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Column(children: [
              Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      controller: myController,
                      maxLines: 5,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    )),
                    SizedBox(width: 15),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          _addComment();
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.send))
                  ]),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Text("${(index + 1)}. " + _items[index]));
                      }))
            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the code you have been using? It 'll help us get to the solution quickly.

Comment: The link is to the code

Comment: Well, if you have code written just copy it here rather than posting a link... it's not convenient for others to look at the question here and look at code somewhere else.

Comment: Also, you haven't posted your code anywhere, there's just a code snippet in the answer.

Comment: That is the code and I can’t post because I’m asking from my phone and when I try to post it says it does not support touchscreen devices,I’m new to every thing flutter and even stackoverflow so if you could help it would mean a lot

Comment: I have added the code in question. Please accept the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `ListView` in some other widget, I have made an example for reference:

```dart
class OtherPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  const OtherPage({Key key, this.items}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Details'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  "${(index + 1)}. " + items[index],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What you need to do is replace the Existing `ListView.Builder` from the `column` with the following Code:

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('OtherPage'),
  onPressed: () {
   Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => OtherPage(
      items: _items,
     ),
    ),
   );
  },
 ),
```

Check this out and let me know in comments if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you so much for even taking the time to help me and the code routes to another page but it doesn’t build the listview.builder content

Comment: I didn’t now what I missed but it is working now I’m so thankful really and how can I ask you if have any other problems

Comment: that's great. well just a post a question with description enough to let us help you & I'll be there... :p

Comment: Hi again @Harshvardhan Joshi sorry but the code does what I mentioned in the the top comment yesterday it routes to the other page but don’t build the listview it just shows an empty page

Comment: Are you getting list of items in the second page or not?

Comment: No I’m not getting anything just the scaffold with the app bar

Comment: I am not asking if you are getting items visually or not. You should check if your getting the list fo items in the constructor of the OtherPage.

Comment: Yes I am and I’m trying the input from a form is that maybe why

Comment: I think you need to update the question with new code changes. I can't help like this man..

Comment: Okay I will post it

Comment: I don't see any changes in the code!! It's not edited.

Comment: I didn’t edit this one I asked a new question with the edited code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59509579/how-to-build-a-list-view-builder-from-a-form-with-values-from-the-form